# MySQL Friendship Relation Count?

Tags: mysql

Table - friends

```
    friend_id     | friend_one    | friend_two   | role 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1:    44               34              34          me
|2:    45               35              35          me
|3:    46               35              34          fri
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to count, who is following and who's the follower.. that's pretty much it, I've gotten some answers below but mostly just giving me static numbers but thank you so far for the help, it's given me a place to start.

Comment: This question has nothing to so with application code; consider removing all such code, leaving just the SQL

Comment: You should remove all php related stuff and restore the table data you just removed

Comment: I have changed and edited some things as well. Thank you. but still not working for the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want simply this:

```
select friend_one, count(*) as count
from friends
where friend_one != friend_two -- fyi such rows shouldn't exist
group by friend_one;
```

if you want the count for a specific user, do this:

```
select count(*) as count
from friends
where friend_one != friend_two -- fyi such rows shouldn't exist
and friend_one = $uid
```

My comment regarding `friend_one != friend_two` is because you seem to have "auto self friend" entries for each user. This is a bad idea IMHO because it adds no value - consider not having such rows.

Comment: Thought it was best to paste it here. I tried this, which returns a constant Number 1, even when I'm following 3 users. pastebin.com/EBcWUMrc If I try this pastebin.com/cSpPJXNc I get a constant 3, did I do something wrong?